# matplotlib: how to change figure size?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here's my code, and I'd like to set a size for the output image:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
color = 'tab:red'
ax1.plot(range(len(d)), d, color=color)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()

color = 'tab:blue'
ax2.plot(range(len(pips)), pips, color=color)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Take a look at `plt.figure(figsize=(x,y))`

Comment: ^ or `fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(x,y))`